# Start services.msc attached to remote computer

Tags: automation

Is there a way to start services.msc already attached to a remote system (e.g. from command line)? I want to avoid clicking Action -> Connect to remote computer, because I have to do it so often...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start mmc.exe and create a new, custom console that contains the objects you want to use.

You can store these and run them from anywhere as long as they contain remote machine names.

Answer (score 9):

`services.msc /computer=Gregg1`

I thought this wasn't possible, but after I found [this other question & answer](https://serverfault.com/a/565879/131761) it worked wonders for me! They listed the better tool (Computer Management) which shows Event Viewer, Services, Disk Management, Device Manager:
`compmgmt.msc -a /computer=Gregg1`

The `-a` doesn't appear to be necessary, I am honestly confused what it does even after reading [the mmc documentation on it](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757725%28WS.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I've love to start `RSOP.msc` attached to remote PC (to trigger in a script) & haven't found a way to do it from the command-line. If anyone knows how to do it I think it'd be a helpful to put in a comment

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for reviving a dead post but for anyone searching for this answer, another option is to use the sc.exe command line tool.  It will allow you to manipulate services at the command line.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490995.aspx

Another possible alternative (that I'm currently using but trying to get rid of(hence how I found this post lol)) is using a custom built Auto-It macro that opens the plugin and goes through the step-by-step that you're trying to avoid.  I do the same with the printmanagement.msc, msinfo32, and regedit tools as well.

Comment: On the command line, of course, you can also use PowerShell or WMI or sc.exe for performing any service related tasks.