# Use Services Snap-in to Manage Remote Computer not Connected to Domain

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows, remote-access

I have remote machine that I would like to manage using `services.msc`. The machine is not connected to the domain so I can't run the management tools as a user that the remote machine knows about.

When I use `eventvwr`, I'm able to specify a user that exists on the remote machine:
[Event Viewer has "Connect as another user" option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJlhj.png)

However, neither `services` nor 'compmgmt.msc' have this option:
[missing option for services/compmgmt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vE2YV.png)

(I don't have enough reputation yet to inline the images, sorry!)

Is there a way to get this functionality for `services.msc`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can use a command line prompt along with RunAs to handle this:

`runas /user:<COMPUTER\username> Compmgmt.msc –a /computer=COMPUTER`

That should work for you....

Comment: this does not work. it does not prompt for credentials, exactly how the OP described.  I tried the "net use", which works perfect for file explorer, but does not apply to compmgmt.msc

Comment: I think you will never see the problem if your workstation uses the same domain user as the server.

Comment: @rocketsarefast - you are correct..I edited my answer

Comment: Personally, I used `runas /netonly /user:Administrator "mmc compmgmt.msc /computer=10.0.2.15"`. I needed `/netonly` because the account I wanted to use did not also exist on my client machine (I think that’s what that flag is for…?). When I left out `mmc`, the command complained `193: compmgmt.msc /computer=10.0.2.15 is not a valid Win32 application.`.

Answer (score 0):

If the machine you are connecting to does not allow access with your credentials, is not a member of your forest, or is not joined to a domain; then there is one easy way to get all of your tools working. If you use the command line tool for drive mapping, you can also create an authenticated RPC session between your machines which will be used in any access attempt you make after this.

(MAP A DRIVE USING ALTERNATE CREDENTIALS)!!

then you can connect to remote computer via local services or component management tools

*S*

ExShire

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone downvoted you -- your answer was precisely the correct one!